# c programing for mutual exclusion with different application

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, deadlock, mutual-exclusion

I have a homework. 
each application must wait for each of their activity.
I can write this scenario as pthread however, I must to write this scenario with different application.

I can write application as pthread with following code;

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
printf("I am in i");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
```

requested to me ; Users run application as following format;

```
./application 1
./application 2
./application 3
```

1,2,3 represented thread id value, and each application includes loops, each application in order to run code.

second application will not start until finish first loop of first application, and third application must wait end of first loop of first and second application.

how can i write this application ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use thread primitives, as each process is isolated from each other. You have to use other [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) techniques. I suggest a search for *posix semaphores*.

Comment: Sharing a `pthread_mutex` between applications via shared memory is feasible if your platform supports process-sharing pthread mutexes (see [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html)). Whether that is a legitimate solution to your specific problem is up to you. Honestly from the looks of it I doubt a mutex is sufficient *regardless*.

Comment: "requested to me ; Users run application as following format;" - please clarify: does your task consist only in running the next app after previous loops have finished? I am just trying to connect it with mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you desire can be implemented by means of [interprocess communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). It may be implemented, say, by means of shared memory with bool flag located in it. I don't know what OS you're going to write your app for, so can say nothing more specific at the moment.

Judging from **"./"** and **pthread** I suggest target OS is one of the *nix family, but you'd better clarify it. If it is the case, [shmget](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) and company may suit your needs.

And by the way, you wrote you're going to start app like this:

```
./application 1
./application 2
./application 3
```

which means they will run exactly one after another, otherwise you'd start them in the background:

```
./application 1&
```

If you do have to run them exactly like you described, then you'll have to **fork** and exit from parent in order to return control to shell and run your loop in the child process.

Again, this is relent for *nix systems with bash-like shell.

Comment: what about controlling the sequence of execution? running one process after the other doesn't mean second process will start only after the first one is completed.

Comment: @cbinder How do you mean? I'd like to read on it if you don't mind giving some clues.

Comment: I didn't get how you will use bool variable to make the process execute in sequence. Suppose you have set that as 1 for the first one to proceed and other processes except the first are waiting to get its value to be set as 0 then you can't be sure that 2nd will execute or third one after first one sets it to 0 after it completes and how can you make it sure the processes will execute in sequence if there are 4 or more processes.?

Comment: @cbinder Not execute in sequence, but wait until other process's loop finishes. Why 4 and more if author's talking about 3?

Comment: @cbinder Anyway we'd better wait for Orcun to clarify what he needs exactly.